# Why is ActionResult an abstract class instead of an interface?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, architecture

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reasoning behind ASP.NET MVC ActionResult being an abstract class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327885/reasoning-behind-asp-net-mvc-actionresult-being-an-abstract-class)

The `ActionResult` class is abstract and only declares one abstract method.  There is no implementation in the class.

In my designs I tend to use interfaces for classes that have no implementation or dependencies.  Why would Microsoft have chosen to use a class instead of an interface in this circumstance, and to use an interface for other analogous situations, such as `IModelBinder` for instance.

The source code for the `ActionResult` class:

```
public abstract class ActionResult
{
    protected ActionResult(){}
    public abstract void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context);
}
```